# array on mips from C to MIPS?

Tags: mips

```
B[8] = A[i–j];
```

how do you use the arrays while trying to convert into MIPS the above C expression?
i thought something like :

```
lw $t0, 16 ($s7)
sub $t1, $s3, $s4
lw $t2, $t1 ($s6)
```

considering that

```
$s6 holds A
$s7 --- B
$s3 ---- i
and $s4 -- j
```

but am not sure about how to do the calculationg to actually get on A [i-j]

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off, `16($s7)` is wrong. Assuming that B and A are arrays of 32-bit integers, the offset is `8 * 4 = 32`.

Next, simply add `$t1` and `$s6` and load from there.

```
lw  $t0 32($s7)
sub $t1 $s3 $s4
add $t1 $s6 $t1
lw  $t2 0($t1)
```