# Split String and store into 2 integer variables in MIPS assembly language

Tags: string, assembly, mips

I am currently doing a program that needs user input a string of 7 digits, then split into 2 different integer variables to perform an equation.

**Example for the string is 1900991: I would like to split the first 3 digits 190 into integer G, and the 0991 into integer K so i can use them to do equation with other 2 user defined integer.**

Any help is appreciated. I am super new to the assembly language.....
Thank you!
Below is my code so far

```
.data 
prompt: .asciiz "Please enter a value between 1-99: "
prompt2:.asciiz "Please enter a value between 2-4: "
message1:.asciiz "The first value is "
message2:.asciiz "\nThe second value is "
messageName: .asciiz "\nYour name is "
messageID: .asciiz "\nYour student id is "
messageResult: .asciiz "\nYour result is "
nameInput: .space 20
idInput:.space 20
```

.text

```
main:

li $v0,8
la $a0,nameInput
li $a1,20
syscall

li $v0,8
la $a0,idInput
li $a1,20
syscall

#Display hello
li $v0,4
la $a0,messageName
syscall

#Display name
li $v0,4
la $a0,nameInput
syscall

#Display hello
li $v0,4
la $a0,messageID
syscall

#Display name
li $v0,4
la $a0,idInput
syscall

#Prompt for user value 1
li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt
syscall

#get value 1
li $v0,5
syscall

#store the value 1 into temp value 1
move $t0,$v0

#Prompt for user value 2
li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt2
syscall

#get value 2
li $v0,5
syscall

#store value 2 into temp value 2
move $t1,$v0

#display value 1
li $v0,4
la $a0,message1
syscall

li $v0,1
move $a0,$t0
syscall

#display value 2
li $v0,4
la $a0,message2
syscall

li $v0,1
move $a0,$t1
syscall

#Display result (1)
li $v0,4
la $a0,messageResult
syscall

#Display result
jal equation
li $v0,1
addi $a0,$v1,0
syscall

#tell the system this is the end of main
li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Do you have to accept a 7 digit string and split it into two numbers?  It would be much easier to accept 2 separate numbers.  If the answer is yes, can you write it in C or Java?  That will give you an algorithm, which you can translate into assembly.  You would have to write a simple [`atoi`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-your-own-atoi/) equivalent as MARS & QTSPIM only provide atoi capabilities in the context of reading an integer from the console.

Comment: Halo Erik Eidt, thank you for taking time to helping me out. I have been questioning my lecturer about the limitation on prompting user input whether I can just ask for 2 integer separately and concat them while displaying. However I'm asking in case of the worst situation, if I have to split into 2 in C or java I would use substring method, store the 2 split string into 2 strings then parse them into integer but I am super new in Mips and I'm currently using MARS, is there any way you can enlighten me further :( thank you

Comment: Hello prl thank you for answering my question, but the question I posted is the exact questions too. Prompt user for a string and split into 2 integers

Comment: @teowks000, perl meant to say that it isn't clear what you're stuck on. You should incrementally code your program (first get user input properly, then store that input properly and so on) and when a certain part doesn't work, you can ask about it. Also, the C orJava solution can't be implemented directly, but Erik suggested you to make it in a higher level language first, so you see what the algorithm would look like. For example, look at [this small translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227087/array-on-mips-from-c-to-mips).